# JavaScript file not working without "onload"

Tags: javascript, html

Problem was fixed.
I just create JavaScript code for fit a text. 
https://github.com/foxreaper/font-master/tree/master

Feel free to use. But please send me some examples of your work :D

I have a problem with JavaScript file. 
So. when i have JavaScript code inside HTML everything is working. I use code:

HTML

```
<body onload="start()">
```

JavaScript

```
function start() {
move();
font();
alert();
}
```

i was trying even to replace my "onload" in HTML file for

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
```

but, nothing happen. Any idea?

So, my JavaScript file is not working inside HTML without "onload" and obviously code not working as external file. 
I would like to put my JavaScript code inside a .js extension and load it as a `<script src="mycode.js"></script>`
inside html.

now my code is like this:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
  move();
  font();
  alert();
}
```

and it's working on HTML without "onload", but steal not as external file.

Comment: any console errors in developer tools?

Comment: none. Code is working perfect but only with "onload".

Comment: did you try window.onload = function() {} ?

Comment: code what you mentioned looks fine on codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vRXvPW

Comment: Make sure the addEventListener is not in a deferred/asynced external script, not within another script block / function / method that is executing after the window load or other event, and try to put it in the header if possible. The "load" event will only function when it is added as a listener prior to the event actually firing. If it is added too late the function will not run and the listener will simply sit there for eternity... or until the browser or tab is closed or crashes, whichever comes first.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Internet Explorer (IE) note that addEventListener will only work in IE 9 and greater.

Comment: i using chrome.

Comment: So, for now, code is working without "onload" 
Earlier i was wrapping all functions with window.onload = function() {}  now i change my function start(){} for window.onload = function() {} .

Comment: i fix a issue. after i replace "function start(){}" i had console errors with clientWidth 1 of my variables wasn't working on external file when it was working inside HTML. Anyway thank's everyone for comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `window.onload`. Simply put the `<script>` (tag or inline) just before close of `<body>` tag.

[per Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E):

> The short story is that we don't want to wait for DOMContentReady (or
>   worse the load event) since it leads to bad user experience. The UI is
>   not responsive until all the DOM has been loaded from the network. So
>   the preferred way is to use inline scripts as soon as possible.
>
> initWidget(document.getElementById('my-widget'));
>
> Yes, it not as easy to maintain but it leads to a better user
>   experience.
>
> By intentionally leaving out DOMContentReady wrappers we have been
>   able to prevent Google Apps to use on this anti pattern.

Comment: i have 100 line code, so i don't wont it to be inside body tag.  if you have a idea how to do inside .js go ahead. i will release link on github soon

Comment: use a `<script src="myscript.js">` tag?

Comment: yes. i did that. and window.onload = function(). if you have any idea how to improve my code. go to github